# Using external variable as a variable inside WhenEvent & NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, event-detection

I'm trying to use the new [WhenEvent](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WhenEvent.html) functionality of NDSolve in Mathematica 9, in order to perform an action when a variable in the system reaches a certain value. I would like this variable to come from an external variable, like so:

```
var = y; (* this could come from somewhere else *)
list = {};

(* keep track of values of x for which y[x] == 1 *)
NDSolve[{y''[x] == -y[x], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0, 
  WhenEvent[Round[var[x], 0.1] == 1, AppendTo[list, x]]},
  y, {x, 0, 10}]
```

But this produces the errors

> NDSolve::nbnum1: The function value Round[y[0.],0.1]==1 is not True or
>   False when the arguments are {0.,1.,0.,0.,-1.}. >>
>
> NDSolve::nbnum1: The function value Round[y[0.000143737],0.1]==1 is
>   not True or False when the arguments are
>   {0.000143737,1.,-0.000143737,-0.000143737,-1.}. >>
>
> NDSolve::nbnum1: The function value Round[y[0.000287473],0.1]==1 is
>   not True or False when the arguments are
>   {0.000287473,1.,-0.000287473,-0.000287473,-1.}. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of NDSolve::nbnum1 will be suppressed
>   during this calculation. >>

How can I use an "external" variable to specify which variable to watch in WhenEvent?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `WhenEvent` has the attribute `HoldAll`, so `var` is never translated to `y`.  Here's a standard trick to inject the actual value of `var` into the code:

```
var = y;
Reap[NDSolve[{y''[x] == -y[x], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0, 
  WhenEvent[Round[#[x], 0.1] == 1, Sow[x]]},
  y, {x, 0, 10}]]&[var]

(* Out: {{{y->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.}},<>]}},{{5.99762}}} *)
```

Also, I replaced your `AppendTo` with a `Reap`/`Sow` combination, which is generally a bit more efficient.

There are other ways to inject the variable value into the code as well.  For example:

```
var = y;
Reap[NDSolve[{y''[x] == -y[x], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0, 
  WhenEvent[Round[var2[x], 0.1] == 1, Sow[x]] /. var2 -> var},
  y, {x, 0, 10}]]
```

The ever popular `Evaluate` (although placement of the `Evaluate` is a bit tricky):

```
var = y;
Reap[NDSolve[{y''[x] == -y[x], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0, 
  WhenEvent[Evaluate[Round[var[x], 0.1] == 1], Sow[x]]},
  y, {x, 0, 10}]]
```

And, my personal favorite:

```
var = y;
With[{var=var},
  Reap[NDSolve[{y''[x] == -y[x], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[Round[var[x], 0.1] == 1, Sow[x]]},
    y, {x, 0, 10}]]]
```

Comment: My personal favourite is a replacement rule but the other way around, `var /. var_ :> Reap[...`

Comment: As a general technique, would `WhenEvent[event,action]/.event->PUT YOUR EVENT HERE` work?