# Using WhenEvent to limit the derivative

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

In the system below, would like to keep z[t] between 0 and 1.  The intent of the code below is to use WhenEvent to detect when z[t] reaches the limit of 1, and then only allow negative values of the derivative, so that z[t] could decrease but not increase.  However, in the plots below, z[t] continues to increase. 
Perhaps some user error, but I haven't been able to identify it.

```
df =   4. (0.07 z[t] Sqrt[600. - p[t]] - 0.005 Sqrt[p[t] p[t] - 100.] );
de = {p'[t] == df, z'[t] == -0.3 df + 0.4 (170. - p[t]) };
ic = {p[0] ==  140., z[0] == 0.5};
events = {WhenEvent[z[t] > 1, 
    z'[t] ==  Min[0,  -0.3 df + 0.4 (170. - p[t])] ]};
eqs = Flatten[{de, ic, events}];
solODE = NDSolve[eqs, {p, z}, {t, 0, 20}];
Plot[p[t] /. solODE, {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {All, All}, PlotLabel -> "P[t]" ]
Plot[z[t] /. solODE, {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {All, All}, PlotLabel -> "Z[t]" ]
```

[image: z(t)]
[image: p(t)]

### Follow-up

3 methods that produce the intended results have been identified.

```
tmax = 20;
(*WhenEvent and appropriate expressions*)
df = 4. (0.07 z[t] Sqrt[600. - p[t]] - 0.005 Sqrt[p[t] p[t] - 100.]);
dz = (-0.3 df + 0.4 (170. - p[t]));
de = {p'[t] == df, z'[t] == in[t] dz};
ic = {p[0] == 140., z[0] == 0.5, in[0] == 1};
events = WhenEvent[event, action] /. {
     {event -> z[t] > 1, action -> in[t] -> 0},
     {event -> dz < 0 && z[t] == 1, action -> in[t] -> 1}};
eqs = Flatten[{de, ic, events}];
{pFuncA, zFuncA} = {p[t], z[t]} /. First@NDSolve[eqs, {p, z, in}, {t, 0, tmax}, DiscreteVariables -> {in}];

(*Piecewise and appropriate method for NDSolve*)
dpRHS[z_, p_] := 4. (0.07 z Sqrt[600. - p] - 0.005 Sqrt[p p - 100.])
dzRHS[z_, p_] := Module[{dzVal},
  dzVal = -0.3 dpRHS[z, p] + 0.4 (170. - p);
  Piecewise[{{Max[0, dzVal], z <= 0}, {Min[0, dzVal], z >= 1}}, dzVal]]
de = {p'[t] == dpRHS[z[t], p[t]], z'[t] == dzRHS[z[t], p[t]]};
ic = {p[0] == 140., z[0] == 0.5};
eqs = Flatten[{de, ic}];
{pFuncB, zFuncB} = {p[t], z[t]} /. First@NDSolve[eqs, {p, z}, {t, 0, 20}, Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}];

(*Piecewise and appropriate form for test conditions*)
dpRHS[z_, p_] := 4. (0.07 z Sqrt[600. - p] - 0.005 Sqrt[p p - 100.])
dzRHS[z_, p_] := Module[{dzVal},
   dzVal = -0.3 dpRHS[z, p] + 0.4 (170. - p);
   Piecewise[{{0, (z <= 0 && dzVal < 0) || (z >= 1 && dzVal > 0)}}, 
    dzVal]];
de = {p'[t] == dpRHS[z[t], p[t]], z'[t] == dzRHS[z[t], p[t]]};
ic = {p[0] == 140., z[0] == 0.5};
eqs = Flatten[{de, ic}];
{pFuncC, zFuncC} = {p[t], z[t]} /. First@NDSolve[eqs, {p, z}, {t, 0, tmax}];

(*results*)
plotP = Plot[{pFuncA, pFuncB, pFuncC, 170}, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> {All, All}, PlotLabel -> "P[t]", 
   PlotStyle -> {Sequence, Sequence, Sequence, {Red, Dashing[0.01]} }, ImageSize -> 400];
plotZ = Plot[{zFuncA, zFuncB, zFuncC}, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> {All, All}, PlotLabel -> "Z[t]", ImageSize -> 400];
{plotP, plotZ}
```

Results for all three methods are similar.
[image]

Comment: Your syntax for the action of `WhenEvent` is off - that should be `WhenEvent[…,y[t]'->…]`. `NDSolve` will complain however that you can't set the highest derivative. See @AlexTrounev's answer for a workaround

Comment: "Eventually, the system goes unstable -- which is actually the point of this exercise" -- is the point to demonstrate the instability or to eliminate it?

Comment: this exercise was to demonstrate the instability, subsequent exercise will be to eliminate it.    I observed the instability in another context (outside of Mathematica) and was trying to reproduce it in Mathematica.  What was new to me, was that without any limits on z, (e.g. if z can go above 1 and if z can move very fast) then the system appears to be stable.  However, the physical system does limit the value of z between 0 and 1 and it does limit how fast z can move.  This question was about how to add the limit on the value of z.

Comment: I don’t know, my answer doesn’t show any instability.  It does keep z[t]<1 though.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out.  investigating the reason for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To constrain `NDSolve` to keep one of the variables in bounds, I add an indicator variable `in[t]` that changes from 1 to 0 at the boundary and back to 1 when `z'[t]` becomes negative again, using two `WhenEvents`.

```
df = 4. (0.07 z[t] Sqrt[600. - p[t]] - 0.005 Sqrt[p[t] p[t] - 100.]);
dz = (-0.3 df + 0.4 (170. - p[t]));
de = {p'[t] == df, z'[t] == in[t] dz};
ic = {p[0] == 140., z[0] == 0.5, in[0] == 1};
tmax = 20;
events = WhenEvent[event, action] /. {
  {event -> z[t] > 1, action -> in[t] -> 0}, 
  {event -> dz < 0 && z[t] == 1, action -> in[t] -> 1}
};
eqs = Flatten[{de, ic, events}];
solODE = NDSolve[eqs, {p, z, in}, {t, 0, tmax}, DiscreteVariables -> {in}];
Plot[p[t] /. solODE, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotLabel -> "P[t]"]
Plot[z[t] /. solODE, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotLabel -> "Z[t]"]
Plot[in[t] /. solODE, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotLabel -> "in[t]"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here are the dynamics superimposed on the phase plane (including isoclines), with the boundary at `z=1` indicated:

```
Show[
  myStreamPlot[{dz, df}, {z[t], 0.5, 1.05}, {p[t], 140, 175}, StreamPoints -> Fine, StreamStyle -> Gray],
  ContourPlot[{dz == 0, df == 0}, {z[t], 0.5, 1.05}, {p[t], 140, 175}],
  Graphics[Line[{{1, 140}, {1, 175}}]],
  ParametricPlot[{z[t], p[t]} /. solODE, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotStyle -> Pink],
  FrameLabel -> {z, p}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`myStreamPlot` is from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157613/6358), originally by @Rahul.

As to the weird way to define the `WhenEvents`, [this answer by Mark McClure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16232/6358) notes that `WhenEvent` has the attribute `HoldAll`.  [This answer by Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39393/6358) explains why the order `dz < 0 && z[t] == 1` is required in the second `WhenEvent`.

Comment: Thanks! this provides some direction and tools for going forward.

Answer (score 2):

It can be easier

```
df = 4.*(0.07 z[t] Sqrt[600. - p[t]] - 0.005 Sqrt[p[t]^2 - 100.]);
F = If[z[t] <= 
    1, -0.3*4.*(0.07 z[t] Sqrt[600. - p[t]] - 
       0.005 Sqrt[p[t]^2 - 100.]) + 0.4 (170. - p[t]), 
   Min[0, -0.3*4.*(0.07 z[t] Sqrt[600. - p[t]] - 
        0.005 Sqrt[p[t]^2 - 100.]) + 0.4*(170. - p[t])]];
de = {p'[t] == df, z'[t] == F};
ic = {p[0] == 140., z[0] == 0.5};
eqs = Flatten[{de, ic}];
solODE = NDSolve[eqs, {p, z}, {t, 0, 20}]
{Plot[p[t] /. solODE, {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {All, All}, 
  PlotLabel -> "P[t]"],
 Plot[z[t] /. solODE, {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {All, All}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Z[t]"], 
 Plot[z[t] /. solODE, {t, 0, .1}, PlotRange -> {All, All}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Z[t]"]}
```

[image: fig1]
As pointed out by Chris, the solution depends on the method

```
solODE = NDSolve[eqs, {p, z}, {t, 0, 20}, 
  Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}]
```

[image: fig2]

Comment: any thoughts about why z[t] did not settle out to the same value as the original posting?

Comment: Why should it be like in your mistaken solution of equations?

Comment: because when p[t] is 170, for p'[t] to be zero, then z[t] should be 0.58.  Put another way, p'[t] = df, and NSolve[ 0 ==  df /. p[t] -> 170, z[t]], yields {{z[t] -> 0.584567}}

Comment: the system eventually goes unstable, which I suspected, but wasn't seeing when z was increasing beyond 1.  There is a delay for the instability to occur, probably because the NDSolve is taking increasingly smaller step sizes.  The instability occurs much earlier when a simple solutions method, like ExplicitEuler, is used.

Comment: The system is really unstable, check `Plot[z[t] /. solODE, {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "Z[t]"]`

Comment: Yes.  It seems that without out the limit on z, the system can find its way to the fixed point at (z = 0.585, p = 170), but with the limit on z, the system becomes unstable.

Comment: The system is unstable here because the solution does not leave z[t]=1 when it should.

Comment: @ChrisK Why should the equation solution `z[t]` leave 1?

Comment: If you look at the phase plane in my answer, once p[t] gets larger than the isocline, z’[t] becomes negative so z[t] should decrease.

Comment: @ChrisK This is a mistake, because the condition `z'[t] ==  Min[0,  -0.3 df + 0.4 (170. - p[t])] ]` at `z[t]>1` changes the solution of the equation.

Comment: If `-0.3 df + 0.4 (170. - p[t]) <0` then isn't `Min[0, -0.3 df + 0.4 (170. - p[t])]==-0.3 df + 0.4 (170. - p[t])<0` too?

Comment: Interestingly, if you add `Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}` to your `NDSolve` it matches my solution.

Comment: @ChrisK +1 You're right, it depends on the method.