# Using WhenEvent to Bound Variables

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

I would like to use the `WhenEvent` function ([link here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveWhenEvents.html)) to set a bound on a dynamic variable in a set of ODEs. That is, when the variables `k21[t]` and `k12[t]` reach above specific value `a`, I would like to set them back at that value. A simplified version of the problem looks like

```
w1 = 6/24.5;
w2 = 6/23.5;
a = 0.1;

Eqs = {
   x1'[t] == w1 + (k21[t]/2)*Sin[x2[t] - x1[t]],
   x2'[t] == w2 + (k12[t]/2)*Sin[x1[t] - x2[t]],
   k21'[t] == a*(Cos[x2[t] - x1[t] + \[Pi]] + 1),
   k12'[t] == a*(Cos[x1[t] - x2[t] + \[Pi]] + 1)};

ICs = {x1[0] == 3/2, x2[0] == 3/4, k21[0] == 0.0001, k12[0] == 0.0001};

events = {WhenEvent[Abs[k21[t]] > a, k21[t] -> a], WhenEvent[Abs[k12[t]] > a, k12[t] -> a]};

EqsICs = Join[Eqs, ICs, events];

SolutionValue[t_] = NDSolveValue[EqsICs, {x1[t], x2[t], k21[t], k12[t]}, {t, 0, 10^6}];
```

And I plot the solutions as:

```
Show[
Plot[SolutionValue[t][[3]], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> {{0, tmax}, {-0.1, 0.1}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], 
Plot[SolutionValue[t][[4]], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> {{0, tmax}, {-0.1, 0.1}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
]
```

However, my `WhenEvent`doesn't work. The plot shows that the values of `kij` keep growing beyond `a`. Is my syntax wrong? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of `WhenEvent` can be a little misleading.  A `WhenEvent` is triggered by an *event* that happens at a particular time value, not a condition.  In your case, `Abs[k21[t]] > a` is only triggered at the moment `Abs[k21[t]]` passes through `a` from below, but it is not detected afterwards.  Therefore this doesn't keep `k21` in bounds.

The approach that works for me (example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/188917/6358)) is to multiply each equation by a `DiscreteVariable` that indicates whether that variable is in-bounds (1) or not (0).  One event is when the variable reaches the boundary, set the indicator to 0.  The other event you'll need is when the variable changes to being pushed back in from the boundary, set the indicator back to 1.  This prevents getting stuck on the boundary forever.

In your case there are four possible events (`k12` and `k21` could each become `> a` or `< -a`).  The following seems to work (note I switched to `NDSolve`, replaced `1` by a constant `c` to test other cases, and reduced `tmax` to 100):

```
w1 = 6/24.5;
w2 = 6/23.5;
a = 0.1;

c = 1;
tmax = 100;

Eqs = {
   x1'[t] == w1 + (k21[t]/2)*Sin[x2[t] - x1[t]],
   x2'[t] == w2 + (k12[t]/2)*Sin[x1[t] - x2[t]],
   k21'[t] == in[k21][t] (a*(Cos[x2[t] - x1[t] + π] + c)),
   k12'[t] == in[k12][t] (a*(Cos[x1[t] - x2[t] + π] + c))
   };

ICs = {x1[0] == 3/2, x2[0] == 3/4, k21[0] == 0.0001, k12[0] == 0.0001,
    in[k12][0] == 1, in[k21][0] == 1};

events = {
  WhenEvent[k21[t] > a, in[k21][t] -> 0],
  WhenEvent[a*(Cos[x2[t] - x1[t] + π] + c) < 0 && in[k21][t] == 0, in[k21][t] -> 1],
  WhenEvent[k21[t] < -a, in[k21][t] -> 0],
  WhenEvent[a*(Cos[x2[t] - x1[t] + π] + c) > 0 && in[k21][t] == 0, in[k21][t] -> 1],
  WhenEvent[k12[t] > a, in[k12][t] -> 0],
  WhenEvent[a*(Cos[x1[t] - x2[t] + π] + c) < 0 && in[k12][t] == 0, in[k12][t] -> 1],
  WhenEvent[k12[t] < -a, in[k12][t] -> 0],
  WhenEvent[a*(Cos[x1[t] - x2[t] + π] + c) > 0 && in[k12][t] == 0, in[k12][t] -> 1]
};

EqsICs = Join[Eqs, ICs, events];

sol = NDSolve[
   EqsICs, {x1, x2, k21, k12, in[k12], in[k21]}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
   DiscreteVariables -> {in[k12], in[k21]}];

Plot[Evaluate[{k21[t], k12[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Evidently you do get stuck on the top boundary. If we reduce `c` to 0.95, we can see that you can leave the boundary:

[image]