# Using WhenEvent to stop N objects at a boundary

Tags: differential-equations, physics, animation, event-detection

I am attempting to implement an event into my simulation which makes any moving particle in an electric field completely stop at the instant they pass some specified threshold.

I was trying to utilize DiscreteVariable, as presented in other threads to accomplish this:

[Using WhenEvent to Bound Variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218774/using-whenevent-to-bound-variables)

[Using WhenEvent to limit the derivative](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188899/using-whenevent-to-limit-the-derivative?rq=1),

but can't seem to work it out in my particular application.

The boundary I am trying to implement is seen here under `event`:

```
eqs = Table[{x1[j]''[t] == -(1/mass)*eforceX[x, y, z] /. {x -> 
       x1[j][t], y -> y1[j][t], z -> z1[j][t]},
    y1[j]''[t] == -(1/mass)*eforceY[x, y, z] /. {x -> x1[j][t], 
      y -> y1[j][t], z -> z1[j][t]},
    z1[j]''[t] == -(1/mass)*eforceZ[x, y, z] /. {x -> x1[j][t], 
      y -> y1[j][t], z -> z1[j][t]},
    x1[j][0] == pos0[[j, 1, 1]],
    y1[j][0] == pos0[[j, 2, 1]],
    z1[j][0] == pos0[[j, 3, 1]],
    x1[j]'[0] == vel0[[j, 1, 1]],
    y1[j]'[0] == vel0[[j, 2, 1]],
    z1[j]'[0] == vel0[[j, 3, 1]]},
   {j, numbodies}];

partRad = 0.025/2;

vars = Flatten[Table[{x1[j][t], y1[j][t], z1[j][t]}, {j, numbodies}]];

event = Table[{WhenEvent[ 
      z1[j][t] >= -partRad , {x1[j]'[t] -> 0, y1[j]'[t] -> 0, 
       z1[j]'[t] -> 0}]} /. {j -> i}, {i, numbodies}];

sol1 = NDSolve[{eqs, event}, Head /@ vars, {t, 0, tfin}]
```

How would one go about setting up an actual boundary condition, such that if one of the N particles passes the boundary `z1[j][t] >= -partRadius`, they completely stop?

The full program is shown here:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

q = 1.617733*10^-18;(*Net ion Charge*)

R= Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/dds8rm3odg2m7gu/largeAp.obj?dl=\
1"];

RegionDimension[R];
M = BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[R], MeshCells[R, 2]];
RegionDimension[M];
Volume[M];

r = RegionDifference[
   RegionDifference[
    RegionDifference[Cuboid[{0, 0, -6.5}, {2, 2, 0.5}], M], 
    Cuboid[{0, 0, 0.4}, {2, 2, 0.5}]], 
   Cuboid[{0, 0, -6.5}, {2, 2, -6.4}]];
ToElementMesh[r]["Wireframe"];
pol = -1;

V0 = 1000;
sol = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[V[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[
     V[x, y, z] == -pol*
       V0/2, (0.4 <= z <= 0.5) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <= 2)], 
    DirichletCondition[
     V[x, y, z] == 
      pol*V0/2, (0.0071 <= z <= 0.0072) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <=
         2)], DirichletCondition[
     V[x, y, z] == 
      0, (0 <= z <= 0.0070) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <= 2)], 
    DirichletCondition[
     V[x, y, z] == 
      0, (-6.5 <= z <= -6.4) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <= 2)]}, 
   V, {x, y, z} \[Element] r];

electricField[x_, y_, z_] = -Grad[sol[x, y, z], {x, y, z}];

v = Show[VectorPlot3D[
    electricField[x, y, z], {x, 0.5, 1}, {y, 0.5, 1}, {z, -0.5, 0.1}, 
    PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", VectorScale -> 0.05, 
    VectorPoints -> 7, PlotLegends -> Automatic], M];

vecForce = 
  Show[VectorPlot3D[
    q*electricField[x, y, z], {x, 0.5, 1}, {y, 0.5, 
     1}, {z, -0.25, -0.00001}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
    VectorScale -> 0.05, VectorPoints -> 7, PlotLegends -> Automatic],
    M];

numbodies = 3;
mass = 6.52*10^-11;(*particle mass in kg/m^3*)


vel0 = Table[Partition[{0, 0, 0}, 1], numbodies];
(*vel0=Table[Partition[{RandomReal[{-0.0001,0.0001}],RandomReal[{-0.\
0001,0.0001}],RandomReal[{-0.0001,0.0001}]},1],numbodies]*)
pos0 = Table[
   Partition[{RandomReal[{0.5, 1}], RandomReal[{0.5, 1}], 
     RandomReal[{-0.4, -0.04}]}, 1], numbodies];


eforceX[x_, y_, z_] = q*Grad[sol[x, y, z], {x, y, z}][[1]];
eforceY[x_, y_, z_] = q*Grad[sol[x, y, z], {x, y, z}][[2]];
eforceZ[x_, y_, z_] = q*Grad[sol[x, y, z], {x, y, z}][[3]];


tfin = 400;

eqs = Table[{x1[j]''[t] == -(1/mass)*eforceX[x, y, z] /. {x -> 
       x1[j][t], y -> y1[j][t], z -> z1[j][t]},
    y1[j]''[t] == -(1/mass)*eforceY[x, y, z] /. {x -> x1[j][t], 
      y -> y1[j][t], z -> z1[j][t]},
    z1[j]''[t] == -(1/mass)*eforceZ[x, y, z] /. {x -> x1[j][t], 
      y -> y1[j][t], z -> z1[j][t]},
    x1[j][0] == pos0[[j, 1, 1]],
    y1[j][0] == pos0[[j, 2, 1]],
    z1[j][0] == pos0[[j, 3, 1]],
    x1[j]'[0] == vel0[[j, 1, 1]],
    y1[j]'[0] == vel0[[j, 2, 1]],
    z1[j]'[0] == vel0[[j, 3, 1]]},
   {j, numbodies}];

partRad = 0.025/2;

vars = Flatten[Table[{x1[j][t], y1[j][t], z1[j][t]}, {j, numbodies}]];

event = Table[{WhenEvent[ 
      z1[j][t] >= -partRad , {x1[j]'[t] -> 0, y1[j]'[t] -> 0, 
       z1[j]'[t] -> 0}]} /. {j -> i}, {i, numbodies}];

sol1 = NDSolve[{eqs, event}, Head /@ vars, {t, 0, tfin}]


frames = Table[
   Show[v, ParametricPlot3D[
     Table[{x1[j][t], y1[j][t], z1[j][t]} /. sol1, {j, 
       numbodies}], {t, 0, tf}, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> Off], 
    Graphics3D[
     Table[{Hue[.35], 
       Sphere[{x1[j][tf], y1[j][tf], z1[j][tf]} /. sol1, 0.025]}, {j, 
       numbodies}]]], {tf, .025*tfin, tfin, .025*tfin}];
video = ListAnimate[frames, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Comment: Just a quick hint, which I hope is accurate: To stop a variable, say `x[t]`, governed by `x'[t] == vx[t]` for some expression `vx[t]`, use a discrete variable `x'[t] == a[t] * vx[t]`, with initial value `a[0] == 1`. Then use `WhenEvent[x[t] > upperboundary, a[t] -> 0]` to stop `x[t]`. You'll need a discrete variable for each particle, and you'll need to use it to stop each coordinate of a given particle.

Comment: (You'll also need a `WhenEvent` for each possible boundary crossing, potentially as many as two times the number of coordinates times the number of particles.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 That makes sense to me, but I suppose implementation is what is confusing. For instance, in my set of `eqs`, I made `z1[j]''[t] == a[j][t]*(-1/mass)*eforceZ[x, y, z]` and `event = Table[
   WhenEvent[ z1[j][t] >= -partRad , {a[j][t] -> 0} /. {j -> i}], {i, 
    numbodies}];

sol1 = NDSolve[{eqs, event}, Head /@ vars, {t, 0, tfin}, 
  DiscreteVariables -> a]`... This throws an error `"The function a[j] appears as the head of the expression a[j][t]"`.

Comment: You need to set both `{a[j][t] -> 0, z1[j]'[t] -> 0}` since it's a 2nd order equation. Also the `j -> i` should go outside: `Table[WhenEvent[ ...] /. {j -> i}, {i, 2}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 The answer is shown below. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution. Thanks to @Michael E2 in original question comments.

````
Clear["Global`*"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

q = 1.617733*10^-18;(*Net ion Charge*)

(*R= Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/dds8rm3odg2m7gu/largeAp.obj?dl=\
1"];*)

R = Import["C:\\Users\\zaust\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\largeAp.obj"];
RegionDimension[R];
M = BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[R], MeshCells[R, 2]];
RegionDimension[M];
Volume[M];

r = RegionDifference[
   RegionDifference[
    RegionDifference[Cuboid[{0, 0, -6.5}, {2, 2, 0.5}], M], 
    Cuboid[{0, 0, 0.4}, {2, 2, 0.5}]], 
   Cuboid[{0, 0, -6.5}, {2, 2, -6.4}]];
ToElementMesh[r]["Wireframe"];
pol = -1;

V0 = 1000;
sol = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[V[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[
     V[x, y, z] == -pol*
       V0/2, (0.4 <= z <= 0.5) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <= 2)], 
    DirichletCondition[
     V[x, y, z] == 
      pol*V0/2, (0.0071 <= z <= 0.0072) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <=
         2)], DirichletCondition[
     V[x, y, z] == 
      0, (0 <= z <= 0.0070) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <= 2)], 
    DirichletCondition[
     V[x, y, z] == 
      0, (-6.5 <= z <= -6.4) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <= 2)]}, 
   V, {x, y, z} \[Element] r];

electricField[x_, y_, z_] = -Grad[sol[x, y, z], {x, y, z}];

v = Show[VectorPlot3D[
    electricField[x, y, z], {x, 0.5, 1}, {y, 0.5, 1}, {z, -0.5, 0.1}, 
    PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", VectorScale -> 0.05, 
    VectorPoints -> 7, PlotLegends -> Automatic], M];

vecForce = 
  Show[VectorPlot3D[
    q*electricField[x, y, z], {x, 0.5, 1}, {y, 0.5, 
     1}, {z, -0.25, -0.00001}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
    VectorScale -> 0.05, VectorPoints -> 7, PlotLegends -> Automatic],
    M];

numbodies = 3;
mass = 6.52*10^-11;(*particle mass in kg/m^3*)


vel0 = Table[Partition[{0, 0, 0}, 1], numbodies];
(*vel0=Table[Partition[{RandomReal[{-0.0001,0.0001}],RandomReal[{-0.\
0001,0.0001}],RandomReal[{-0.0001,0.0001}]},1],numbodies]*)
pos0 = Table[
   Partition[{RandomReal[{0.5, 1}], RandomReal[{0.5, 1}], 
     RandomReal[{-0.4, -0.04}]}, 1], numbodies];
discreteStart = Table[Partition[{1, 1, 1}, 1], numbodies];

eforceX[x_, y_, z_] = q*Grad[sol[x, y, z], {x, y, z}][[1]];
eforceY[x_, y_, z_] = q*Grad[sol[x, y, z], {x, y, z}][[2]];
eforceZ[x_, y_, z_] = q*Grad[sol[x, y, z], {x, y, z}][[3]];


tfin = 600;

eqs = Table[{x1[j]''[t] == -a[t]*(1/mass)*eforceX[x, y, z] /. {x -> 
       x1[j][t], y -> y1[j][t], z -> z1[j][t]},
    y1[j]''[t] == -a[t]*(1/mass)*eforceY[x, y, z] /. {x -> x1[j][t], 
      y -> y1[j][t], z -> z1[j][t]},
    z1[j]''[t] == -a[t]*(1/mass)*eforceZ[x, y, z] /. {x -> x1[j][t], 
      y -> y1[j][t], z -> z1[j][t]},
    x1[j][0] == pos0[[j, 1, 1]],
    y1[j][0] == pos0[[j, 2, 1]],
    z1[j][0] == pos0[[j, 3, 1]],
    x1[j]'[0] == vel0[[j, 1, 1]],
    y1[j]'[0] == vel0[[j, 2, 1]],
    z1[j]'[0] == vel0[[j, 3, 1]],
    a[0] == 1},
   {j, numbodies}];

partRad = 0.0125;

vars = Flatten[Table[{x1[j][t], y1[j][t], z1[j][t]}, {j, numbodies}]];

(*event=Table[{WhenEvent[ z1[j][t]\[GreaterEqual] -partRad \
,{x1[j]'[t]\[Rule] 0,y1[j]'[t]\[Rule] 0,z1[j]'[t]\[Rule] 0}]}/.{j\
\[Rule]i},{i,numbodies}];*)

event = Table[
   WhenEvent[ 
     z1[j][t] >= -partRad , {a[t] -> 0, x1[j]'[t] -> 0, 
      y1[j]'[t] -> 0, z1[j]'[t] -> 0}] /. {j -> i}, {i, numbodies}];

sol1 = NDSolve[{eqs, event}, Head /@ vars, {t, 0, tfin}, 
  DiscreteVariables -> a]


frames = Table[
   Show[v, ParametricPlot3D[
     Table[{x1[j][t], y1[j][t], z1[j][t]} /. sol1, {j, 
       numbodies}], {t, 0, tf}, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> Off], 
    Graphics3D[
     Table[{Hue[.35], 
       Sphere[{x1[j][tf], y1[j][tf], z1[j][tf]} /. sol1, 0.025]}, {j, 
       numbodies}]]], {tf, .015*tfin, tfin, .015*tfin}];
video = ListAnimate[frames, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```
````